# Rails how to prevent previous instances of a record from being updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

My question might be a bit confusing but I'll try my best to explain. Basically, I have records that need to be preserved once created and that need to maintain their previous information when a user goes and updates a record. I don't know the correct way to do this but there are a few methods I have considered.

I have two tables that are associated:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

and

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :invoices, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

So I need to figure out how I can preserve invoices data (customer data) if the user were to go and update the customer's information. (In real life, if a customers email changed it would not change existing invoices obviously) Invoices should basically not be allowed to be altered once created, but they have a customer's info associated with each one and I need to somehow preserve that old information for each invoice.

Basically, all I am doing now is disabling all fields so that the user CAN NOT edit a customers information ( I also changed the model to `attr_readonly` and passed in all of the fields) which works but Is restrictive as a customers information can't be changed ever.

Is there a way to obtain the functionality I am after? If so, ideally customers information would be editable but it would not change for previously created invoice records that were associated with that customer.

Am I just way off with my approach? Should I be rethinking my associations? Or should both customer and invoice information just not be editable and the user would just create new records if information for a customer changed? (Think of a general contractor such as a landscaper doing jobs for customers and creating invoices. If a customers phone number changed, you would edit their number in your app, but it should not go and change all invoices you have previously created for that customer. Customer information is more or less just for referencing, customers can be marked as reoccurring so those customers information is subject to change and that would create the problem I am trying to solve)

Comment: I had to deal with invoices in a previous app, we handled that challenge by copying the customer's required data to the invoices table (or a related `invoice_contact` table, I can't remember) and make it readonly + undeletable. Sort of a snapshot of the different "satellite records" of the invoice. -- Also, I would not recommend to add this `dependent: :destroy` on the `Customer`'s `has_many :invoices`. You probably want to keep track of all of the Invoice that ever existed. Maybe use a "soft-delete" (or state machine) for the Customer and make it inactive instead of deleting it

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to save all data needed to display an invoice in the invoice table, when the invoice is created. A customer can change it's data, but the invoice will remain intact.

You can also consider pulling out some data in a separate models. For example `EmailAddress` or `Address`. A customer can then create new email addresses or addresses but the old data remains. However, this approach works only to some extend. It could lead to some artificially created models with awkward names. It's also a more complex solution as you have to keep in mind which models are read only and which can be freely updated.

For that reason, I think that keeping everything related to invoices in a single table is a better and more error proof solution, even though there is some redundancy.

Comment: Your invoice should have user’s denormalized data. You’ll have to persist these data in another table cos it’ll belong to the invoice. User might want to change his phone personal information, and to forbid that may not be the best approach.